# Form parameters unpermitted by in rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, erb

I have a controller for Walkers with the following action:

```
def update
    if !current_user
        redirect_to "/walkers"
    end
    walker = Walker.find(params[:id])
    walker.update(walker_params)
    walker.save
    redirect_to admin_path
end
```

There is also a private method:

```
    def walker_params
        params.require(:walker).permit(:id, :fname, :lname, :role, :active, :role, :avatar)
    end
```

In my resources I have:

```
resources :walkers
```

Then I have a form with the following erb.

```
    <%= form_for :walker, url: "/walkers/#{w.id}", method: "put" do |f| %>
      <%= f.hidden_field active: false %>
      <%= f.submit "Deactivate", class: "font-color-warning mdl-button" %>
    <% end %>
```

My rails server gives me the following error:

```
Unpermitted parameter: {:active=>false}
```

The parameters being sent are:

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓",
"authenticity_token"=>"7vkuiaZG32x0EPr9IR9VvgURTQ7uniZH/7IPfMYdvb3AIGq8Psd+o9ykfs6qMKcozXYm08BKJ0/M3s5Q2DwiGg==", 
"walker"=>{"{:active=>false}"=>""}, 
"commit"=>"Deactivate", 
"id"=>"1"}
```

My expectation was that I was putting false on the :active parameter of the walker object found at PUT 'walkers/w.id'. My parameters show that my expectation is not correct.

I would like a solution to my problem. Ideally some understanding of why my parameters are being sent with `walker"=>{"{:active=>false}"=>""}` when my goal is submit parameters with `walker"=>{:active=>false}`.

I don't have an @walker object to reference because I'm looping through with |w|.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change

```
<%= f.hidden_field active: false %>
```

to

```
 <%= f.hidden_field :active, value: false %>
```

Comment: Would you please accept it, as it solves your problem.

Comment: Yes, I need to wait one more minute it says.